# CMake/CPack: Deploy binary from Linux to Mac OSX

Tags: linux, macos, cmake, cpack

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` that generates my application. I'm working on a Linux machine (Ubuntu 18.04), I need to share this app with a teammate who works on Mac OSX.

What changes I have to make on my `CMakeLists.txt` and which commands should I run in the terminal?

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17 FATAL_ERROR)
project(MyProject)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "many paths...")

find_package(MITK CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)

add_executable(app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(  app
                        MitkCore
                        MitkQtWidgetsExt
)
```

Comment: You're likely to have to worry about how to get the MitkCore and MitkQtWidgetsExt packages  (or maybe it is just MITK and OpenMP) built and installed on macOS before you do anything else.  After that, probably not very much needs to change.  However, I fear that the MITK requirement may be a major hurdle (and maybe OpenMP too, but maybe not, and it is likely less of a hurdle).

Comment: Google search terms 'mitk for macos' and 'openmp for macos' indicate some of the work required.  You could also poke at macOS package systems like Brew (Fink, …) and see whether they can help.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It has been 2 weeks since I started learning how to use, both MITK and CMake. MITK is a huge project, which is dependent on many 3rd party libraries. It can be used as a framework or toolkit. Documentation for using MITK as a framework is extensive and detailed, I can write code to be used as a plugin for a main pre-made app, compilation happens with a series of configurable cmake files. After that I can generate packages for linux and windows, also don't know how to generate for Mac in this case, all dependencies are resolved by cmake.

Comment: I'd not even heard of MITK before looking at this question — I cannot help any further. All I've done is give you a heads up that it may not be as trivial to port your code as you'd like, but OTOH the work may already be available precompiled and simply needing to be installed.  That's something you'll have to assess, using the Google search terms I suggested, or others of your own devising, or by some other technique.  I cannot easily give more help — I'm not aware of knowing anything relevant.